# How to remove the [@attributes] in the SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml, feed

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [domain] => http://www.eatingwell.com/category/publication/magazine /september/october_2009
        )

    [0] => September/October 2009
    [1] => American
    [2] => Easy
    [3] => Diabetes appropriate
    [4] => Healthy weight
    [5] => High calcium
    [6] => Low calorie
    [7] => Low cholesterol
    [8] => Bone Health
    [9] => Super Bowl
    [10] => Recipes & Menus - Fresh
    [11] => Recipes & Menus - Vegetarian
    [12] => Cheese
    [13] => Dairy
    [14] => Greens
    [15] => Vegetables
    [16] => Wheat
    [17] => Whole Grains
    [18] => Vegetarian, other
    [19] => Appetizers 
    [20] => Dinnerâ€¨
    [21] => Bake
    [22] => Fall
    [23] => Spring
    [24] => Summer
    [25] => Winter
    [26] => Budget
    [27] => Entertaining, casual 
    [28] => Everyday favorites
    [29] => Quick (total 30 min. or less)
    [30] => Vegetarian
    [31] => Appetizer
    [32] => Main dish, vegetarian
    [33] => Pizza
)
```

I want retrieved the category from rss feed, but `$bullet =$item->category;pr($bullet);` it display the above result. I want only the array value [0] to [33]. How to remove the @attributes from above result?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
unset(xml->attributes()->domain);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `pr()` is a function which just wraps `print_r()` for whatever reason, in which case I'll tell you what I tell everyone with SimpleXML questions: **don't trust print_r** (or var_dump, or any of the normal debug output functions).

The simple truth is *those properties don't exist*. SimpleXML uses iterators, magic methods, and other tricks to give an incredibly handy "Do What I Mean" interface, but it's very hard to summarise that in debug output.

If you want to loop over all the elements with the same name, write `foreach ( $item->category as $bullet )`, and you will never find `$bullet` being set to any attributes. It will be set to an object for each node, though, so if you're doing something more complex than `echo $bullet`, you probably want to extract the text content with `(string)$bullet`.

If you do want to get an attribute, you won't find it by looking at @attributes in any form, but by using array-style access, e.g. `(string)$bullet['domain']`.

Base your code on [the examples in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), rather than debug output, and you'll get much farther :)

Answer (score -1):

Per IMSoP's observation, @attributes isn't a real property of that object. However, you can "cheat" by doing something like the following, as long as you don't need to interact with the object as a SimpleXMLElement object any more:

```
<?php

function purgeAttributes( $object ) {
    foreach ( $object as $key => $value ) {
        if ( gettype( $value ) == 'object' ) {
            $object->$key = purgeAttributes( $value );
        }

        if ( $key == '@attributes' ) {
            unset( $object->$key );
        }
    }

    return $object;
}

$x = SimpleXML_load_string('<foo bar="baz" />');

$x = json_decode( json_encode( $x ) );

$x = purgeAttributes( $x );

var_dump( $x );
```

Comment: This won't work (test for yourself: http://3v4l.org/a6MFh) and nor will anything similar, because that property doesn't actually exist, it's just how print_r tries to show you what the XML node contains.

Comment: OK, sure, you can turn the useful object into a useless stdClass and then manipulate that. Clever, if rather pointless IMHO: the premise of the question is the same mistake you made, that the attributes will show up like a normal property. You should probably edit your answer with the working code.

Answer (score -1):

I did this, seems to work. An encode->decode should be enough to convert the SimpleXMLElement Object to a StdClass Object and operate the way you want it :

public function cleanXML($xmlString)
    {

```
    $xmlString = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $xmlString);
    $xmlString = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $xmlString));
    $object = SimpleXML_load_string($xmlString);
    $object = json_decode( json_encode( $object ) );
    foreach ( $object as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $key == '@attributes' ) {
            unset( $object->$key );
        }
    }
    return $object;
}
```

Comment: As I said below the other answer, *there is no reason to do this*. Converting to a `stdClass` object like this just *throws away all the functionality of SimpleXML*, and throwing away the `@attributes` property while you do it *throws away part of the XML you're processing*. Honestly, just extract *the data you need*, using [the really simple facilities SimpleXML provides](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), rather than hacking around with string replacements and generic pseudo-objects like this.